# Powershell date range

Tags: powershell, date

I'd like to create a variable that contains a list of dates in the `yyyy_MM_dd` format, one week from a given date.

My current code works, but is not efficient or very clean. Ideally the oldest date (-6 days in the below example) would be a separate variable such as `$lastDate = '-6'` so that I can quickly make adjustments, while still having the script pull the following six days (one week) from the date indicated in `$lastDate`.

I plan to use this variable to find paths containing the date in the particular format, so it is ok if the output is a string and not a real 'date'. I do not want to use date filters on `Get-ChildItem` because the actual dates of the file paths are not accurate to the path names.

Current Script:

```
$range = (Get-Date).AddDays(-6).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd'), (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd'), (Get-Date).AddDays(-4).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd'), (Get-Date).AddDays(-3).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd'), (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd'), (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd'), (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd')
```

This returns the desired results:

```
2019_11_28
2019_11_29
2019_11_30
2019_12_01
2019_12_02
2019_12_03
2019_12_04
```

Can anyone suggest a cleaner or more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like the following?

```
$range = -6..0 | 
    ForEach-Object { (Get-Date).AddDays($_).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd') }
$range
```

> ```
> 2019_11_28
> 2019_11_29
> 2019_11_30
> 2019_12_01
> 2019_12_02
> 2019_12_03
> 2019_12_04
> ```

Comment: This works, to solve for the second ask I added the oldest date as a separate variable:

`$startDate = '-6'
$dateRange = $startDate..0 | 
    ForEach-Object { (Get-Date).AddDays($_).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd') }`